# debug sbt sources too with eclipse

Tags: scala, sbt, sbteclipse

I'd like to navigate to the sbt sources when I debug my sbt build.

By using the sbt eclipse plugin I can debug e.g. my Build.scala file, which is great!  And I can include the sbt plugin sources too by using:

```
> reload plugins
> eclipse withSources=true
```

But the sources to sbt itself aren't in the .classpath file generated by sbt-eclipse.  I see that the source jars are in the ivy cache, but the sourcepath entry is missing:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" 
  path="/home/lee/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-sbt/main-settings/jars/main-settings-0.13.1-RC2.jar"
/>
```

I'd like the generated class path to have a sourcepath like the following. (This was edited manually, I'd like to have it generated by sbt-eclipse):

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" 
  path="/home/lee/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-sbt/main-settings/jars/main-settings-0.13.1-RC2.jar" 
  sourcepath="/home/lee/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-sbt/main-settings/srcs/main-settings-0.13.1-RC2-sources.jar"
/>
```

(Tested with sbt 13.1-RC2 and sbt eclipse 2.4.0)

I see this [sbt-dependency-manager](https://github.com/sbt-android-mill/sbt-dependency-manager) plugin, but that looks awkward...

Is there an easier way to view sbt sources along with my sbt build?

Comment: This is actually an issue with the confiuration we publish sbt settings as.   Can you open a bug in sbt about it using a non-standard sources "flag" when it publishes?  that's why these don't show up.  IIRC, sbt is using the string "srcs", but everyone else uses "sources" or some such sillyness.

Comment: added issue https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/991

Answer (score 0):

I am, as originator of sbt-dependency-manager, must admit that there is not only problem to get sources. You may download sources by hands and manually attach them to your debugger, but Eclipse still unable to use them.

sbt-dependency-manager not only download, but also [repackage jars](https://github.com/digimead/sbt-dependency-manager/blob/79225b1f45f87952c5d0ee87b4e77efe4147cb82/src/main/scala/sbt/dependency/manager/Plugin.scala#L557). So in this way you should open 2 bugs :-):

- about fetch sources in sbt-eclipse
- about sources layout of SBT itself

I tried to avoid this issues and this is only solution that I know. Oh, you may switch to Idea or Ensime, of course - but this is not acceptable for me. Also I don't use sbt-eclipse at all because sbt-dependency-manager makes it useless.

Comment: I tried manually attaching the sbt sources (they seemed to be downloaded to the .ivy/cache, just not put in the .classpath).  After editing the classpath, eclipse navigated to the sbt sources in at least one or two cases I tried.  Where does the sbt sources layout cause a failure?

Comment: Last time when I tried it Eclipse debugger was unable correctly process 'step into', 'step over'. If you have everything working please provide your Scala IDE and Eclipse versions.